# How to trigger remote batch job from Spring Batch Admin?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have two WARs deployed in same jboss application server:-

WAR 1 --> Having Job launcher and job related servies

WAR 2 --> Just have Spring Batch Admin.

I am using same DB repository for both spring batch(WAR1) and spring batch admin(WAR2).

I am able to access all job-related status by using Spring Batch Admin but I am stuck how to trigger the job which is deployed in WAR 1,

I am also able to create the rest web-services in WAR1 with below URL

http://localhost:8080/myJob

But now what would be my next, where I should configure this rest URL in Spring Batch Admin.

It will be great if someone can help me on that.

Answer (score -2):

IIRC Spring Batch Admin can only launch jobs in the same app as itself.

Comment: What is IIRC admin and how it is going to help? I am looking for a solution.

Comment: IIRC is a well-known internet acronym "If I recall correctly"; if my recollection is correct; there is no out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: Ohh It's my bad. But still, I am looking for the solution for above problem.